# Eliminate duplicates before union

Tags: mysql, sql, union, limit

I need to run a query, that select two columns from a big table (3m+ rows, with selecting two columns, the result set is around 6-7m) and returns a list. So I used union to merge the columns into a list and also to eliminate duplicates. The problem is that I cant return the result in one query, I need to partition it, so I applied a `LIMIT ?,?` to the subqueries, which the application layer sets via Prepared Statements.

```
SELECT val
FROM 
(
    (SELECT fs.smr as val
    FROM `fr_search` as fs
    ORDER BY val LIMIT ?,?)

    UNION

    (SELECT fs.dmr as val
    FROM `fr_search` as fs
    ORDER BY val LIMIT ?,?)
) as vals
GROUP BY val
```

The problem: The union eliminates the duplicates, but only after the LIMIT is applied. Meaning If the two query returns 100+100=200 rows and most of them is a duplicate, I only return <200 rows. How can I apply a limit to such a query, that I can return a specific amount of rows? (If I apply the LIMIT after the subqueries, It will take more than two minutes to run, so It will not solve the problem. )

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ...`

Comment: @Psi Using `DISTINCT` achieves what? The same as using `Union` instead of `union all`, the problem persists.

Comment: Why do you have a `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @CraigYoung The subqueries could return the same strings.

Comment: @appl3r You used `UNION`, not `UNION ALL`. The former removes duplicates, and your `GROUP BY` is pointless because it creates groups of 1.

Comment: @CraigYoung True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need a subquery for this.  The following will work for the first 100 rows:

```
 (SELECT DISTINCT fs.smr as val
  FROM `fr_search` as fs
  ORDER BY val
  LIMIT 100
 )
 UNION
 (SELECT DISTINCT fs.dmr as val
  FROM `fr_search` as fs
  ORDER BY val
  LIMIT 100
 )
 ORDER BY val
 LIMIT 100;
```

However, once you start putting in offset, it gets more complicated.  For the next 100 rows:

```
 (SELECT DISTINCT fs.smr as val
  FROM `fr_search` as fs
  ORDER BY val
  LIMIT 200
 )
 UNION
 (SELECT DISTINCT fs.dmr as val
  FROM `fr_search` as fs
  ORDER BY val
  LIMIT 200
 )
 ORDER BY val
 LIMIT 100, 100;
```

The problem is that you don't know where the second set will come from.

If you actually need to page through the result set, I would suggest that you store it in a temporary table and page off of the temporary table.

Comment: I used a temporary table to solve this. Provides little overhead and stable, fast queries while executing.

Answer (score 1):

Query optimisation is always has two parts to the solution. And is sometimes an iterative process of try, measure and compare.

1. Write a good (and ofc accurate) query that the engine can run efficiently.
2. Ensure the appropriate indexes are available so the optimiser can choose a good execution plan.

The best query is most likely the straight-forward and simple:

```
SELECT  v.val
FROM    (
        SELECT  fs.smr as val
        FROM    `fr_search` as fs
        UNION
        SELECT  fs.dmr as val
        FROM    `fr_search` as fs
        ) as v
ORDER BY v.val LIMIT ?,?;
```

In order to run efficiently, you'll want 2 indexes:

- one on `fr_search.smr`
- the other on `fr_search.dmr`

---

If the optimiser cannot handle the above, then try using index hints to force it to use the indexes.

In an extreme pinch you could try forcing the issue with the following:

```
SELECT  v.val
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT fs.smr as val
        FROM    `fr_search` as fs
        ORDER BY fs.smr LIMIT ?
        UNION
        SELECT  DISTINCT fs.dmr as val
        FROM    `fr_search` as fs
        ORDER BY fs.dmr LIMIT ?
        ) as v
ORDER BY v.val LIMIT ?,?;
```

Note that your substitutions (assuming pages of 100) should be as follows:

```
Page 1: 100, 100, 100, 0
Page 2: 200, 200, 100, 100
Page 3: 300, 300, 100, 200
Page 4: 400, 400, 100, 300
etc.
```

The reason is, you need to cater for a possible imbalance of cross column ordering favouring either table. So for example page 4:

- Get top 400 distinct rows ordered by the key from each column.
- Return rows 301 to 400 of the merged data.
- This could be the last 400 rows of one of the sub-queries. But it's more likely to return about 50 rows from each subquery somewhere above the 150 row mark.

Comment: Both indexes are set already, but the table is 1,2GB in size.

Comment: The optimiser _should_ be able to handle this with the appropriate indexes unless you have a huge number of duplicates. However, it might struggle after traversing many pages.

Comment: @appl3r The size of the table is irrelevant if the indexes are used. I don't have Oracle, but on Sql Server: The above query on a table with 5 million rows returns the first 100 rows with 0 ms CPU time and 1 ms Elapsed time. The execution plan shows a selection of a little over 50 rows for each index which are then merged for the final output of the first 100.

Comment: @appl3r In fact if I increase the number of rows returned to the first 10000, significantly more time is spent transmitting the data than was actually required to obtain the data (47 ms va 1 ms).

Comment: Also, I use a MySQL server and I don't think its query optimizer is as good as Sql Server's.

Comment: @appl3r That's unfortunate. I would have expected better of Oracle since they bought the product. I've added some options that might force better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

You can `SELECT DISTINCT` in the inner and outer queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT val
FROM 
(
    (SELECT DISTINCT fs.smr as val
    FROM `fr_search` as fs)

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT DISTINCT fs.dmr as val
    FROM `fr_search` as fs)
) as vals
ORDER BY val LIMIT ?,?;
```

or you can group by your inner queries too, before then grouping by the outer query.

```
SELECT val
FROM 
(
    (SELECT fs.smr as val
    FROM `fr_search` as fs
    GROUP BY fs.smr)

    UNION ALL

    (SELECT fs.dmr as val
    FROM `fr_search` as fs
    GROUP BY fs.dmr)
) as vals
GROUP BY val
ORDER BY val LIMIT ?,?;
```

Both will do essentially the same thing in this particular scenario. However in both you should use union all, so that the `UNION` part doesn't do work on its own, and you are explicit about how you want your record grouping. I would also move the limit clause to the outer query

Comment: Using `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` on subqeuries seems to work, but It takes the same time as running the subqueries without limit and applying it afterwards.

Comment: Your query is going to do a full table scan no matter what because you're wanting distinct values. I doubt there is a way in which you can optimize this. Was the purpose of the question how to get the correct results or was it how to make the query faster?

Comment: Both, I cannot use a query that takes minutes at each call. I need to look into temporary tables for this.

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table? this may help the return time of the query by having the correct ones in place.

Comment: The fields are varchar(100), indexed with BTREE KEYs up to 10 chars. Also, both of the fields are part of a composite UNIQUE Index.

Comment: @appl3r "both of the fields are part of a composite UNIQUE Index" No that's no good! You need 2 separate indexes where each field is the only (or at least the first) index column. Also indexing the first 10 chars is insufficient. The optimiser needs to be certain it can use the indexes to skip duplicates efficiently and use a merge join because a subset of rows from each table is already sorted.

Comment: There are 2 seperate indexes as I mentioned. But also I needed a composite unique check, to not allow insertion of already existing combinations. Mainly I used the index for searching, using the first 10 char decreases the size by far. (indexing whole strings is stupid)

Comment: @appl3r You call indexing whole strings "stupid". Writing tricky counter-intuitive fragile queries to compensate for bad indexes is more so. By indexing only a portion of the strings you miss out on one of the huge benefits of a good index - the ability to retrieve data by ***only*** the index; i.e. not performing a _lookup_ from index to get underlying table data. Such lookups are relatively expensive in the world of query optimisation. As I stated in my answer, correct indexes and experimentation are important. ***Challenge: Try proper indexes with the simple intuitive query.*** (and profit)

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting me to put two varchar(100) field into the index just because this query is slow?? Basically I would index the whole table. What if the table takes 10GB as raw data? You would justify another +10GB for the indexes so you don't need to use a temporary table? Nonsense.

Comment: It's completely situation dependent which approach should be used, however what certainly shouldn't happen is having a composite index of the first 10 chars. That's definitely a waste of index. Having the basic indexes there and the most basic query makes code easier to understand. If you are struggling for memory on your DB server than sure go for the temp table option rather than the large indexes. Regardless of all the above, doing distinct searches on varchar(100) fields is just simply asking for performance issues.

Comment: @appl3r What do have against pulling a query plan with your current indexes and then creating my recommended indexes and retesting and comparing performance and plans? It should take you about 10 minutes and you'll learn something. That said.... I tried to estimate the average length of the strings in your table. But it seems some of the details you've provided are off: Assuming 1.2GB table, 2 columns, and 3.5 mil rows: the average length of each string would be ~170 bytes So I assume the 1.2GB size you quoted is not your data size but includes existing index structures.

Comment: @AdamCopley I have the composite unique key seperate from the two 10 char index.

Comment: @CraigYoung It included the index sizes, but does not matter, the table is growing too fast, no point in arguing about putting big indexes on it.

Comment: @appl3r Define "growing too fast" Can you say what the average length of those `varchar(100)` columns is? Disk space is cheap - that's not what you're supposed to worry about when it comes to index selection. Your focus should be on determining the best balance of indexes to maximise performance for common usage patterns. "Partial indexes" are inferior. You're suffering the overhead of maintaining those indexes on data changes without getting the full benefit of the indexes for data retrieval.

Comment: Additionally only one of the subqueries you have will use the composite index because only one of the columns is the leftmost column. So this is also a wasted index